# Tomcat connection pool connections are dropping

Tags: mysql, tomcat

We are having web applications hosted on Tomcat 7 on CentOS 6 and the applications connects to MySQL database.

We are using the connection pool which keeps check for the connection availability for every 30 min and if any connections are not valid or throwing communication link errors then we are removing those connections from pool and replacing with the new connections.

The applications are freezing after around 90 mins of idle time of database connections in the pool when we try to use them for any query executions.

Any body having any idea what could be the cause.

Comment: When these applications "freeze", can you take a thread dump to see what they are actually doing?